# Select the first N digits of an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table ("Activities") which has a column containing an ID, e.g. "10553100". This is the activity ID and is composed of two parts -> first 4 digits indicates which project it belongs to, and the last 4 digits indicates which sub project.

I need to extract the project number from the `activityId` column (aka the first 4 digits). Is it possible to do this using a simple SELECT statement in SQL?

Comment: As a side remark, it sounds like very poor database design if you ask me... you should have at least two fields for those two values, and maybe you actually only need to store the subproject (which itself belongs to a project I guess)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `LEFT` function.

```
SELECT activityId, LEFT(activityId, 4) AS projectnumber
FROM Activities
```

Or the `SUBSTRING` function.

```
SELECT activityId, SUBSTRING (activityId, 1, 4) AS projectnumber
FROM Activities
```

And if you want too include your subprojectnumber

`LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions.

```
SELECT activityId, LEFT(activityId, 4) AS projectnumber, RIGHT(activityId, 4) AS subprojectnumber
FROM Activities
```

`SUBSTRING` function.

```
SELECT activityId, SUBSTRING (activityId, 1, 4) AS projectnumber, SUBSTRING(activityId, 5, 4) AS subprojectnumber
FROM Activities
```

Answer (score 2):

If the field is numeric then:

```
SELECT Col / 10000 FROM TableName
```

If char the:

```
SELECT LEFT(Col, 4) FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select activity_id / 10000 as project
from activities
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(ActivityId, 4) AS INT) FROM activities
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Select left(activityId,4) from Activities
```

Answer (score 1):

The left command yould work:

```
SELECT LEFT(id, 4) FROM dbo.Activities
```